# Atheros ar8151 driver for kernel 3.x (fedora 16)

Tags: networking, ethernet, drivers

Yesterday, I installed Fedora 16 and found no wireless connection available.

Then I found the [ar81family driver](http://code.google.com/p/iats/downloads/detail?name=AR81Family-Linux-v1.0.1.9.tar.gz&can=2&q=)

But it seems like it does not work with kernel 3. I changed the makefile to ignore the kernel version, but it doesn't compile. It complains:

```
asm/linkage.h not found
```

How can I compile this module for my kernel?

Comment: There may be something wrong with the file you linked to. It seems to contain a driver for a PCI/E ethernet (wired) adapter. Take a look at the readme file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Linux drivers needs to closely match the version of the kernel they were developed for. The driver API changes frequently.

It's one of the many reasons Linux kernel developers very strongly encourage people to submit their drivers.

Usually it's not too hard to update the driver to match the current kernel, especially if the version difference isn't too big. It does require some knowledge of C though.

The easiest solution will be to find out what kernel version the driver was intended to work with and use that one.

Comment: Hm，Actually I am a Java Developer, It is hard for me to modify the driver. But, anyway, I will give a try.

Comment: It's too hard to modify a driver. I think I would pay a lot of to have this done.

Comment: @jilen Have you tried this: http://unknownimous.blogspot.com/2010/08/atheros-ar8151-driver-for-centos.html ?